# Update D3 force layout CSS in real-time

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, knockout.js

I'm building a real-time visualization based on the D3 force layout. I'm able to generate the force layout from an initial set of nodes/edges data. However, the nodes/edges data keep undergoing real-time changes and I need to update various CSS properties of selected graph nodes/edges accordingly - eg: at time t1, node n1's fill color may need to be changed to orange, at t2, edge e1 may change stroke-width, etc.

One option to implements such a system is to redraw the entire graph at each update. However, this is inefficient since

1. The structure of the graph never changes. Only CSS properties associated with the components might change and
2. Frequently redrawing the graph makes the visualization very slow and unresponsive.

So, I've been looking for data-binding options where I could initially utilize d3 to draw the graph and then use a data-binding framework/library such as Angular/Knockout to bind CSS properties of the nodes/edges to the backend data model. However, I couldn't find any helpful references/examples that have adopted such a strategy.

I've used D3 in the past. However, I'm new to Angular and Knockout.

**Questions**

1. Which of the data-binding options would be best in this scenario?
   Angular/Knockout/etc.
2. Are there any examples/reference code that implements something similar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the structure never changes, why not just update by redraw? Redrawing the graph isn't the slow part, it's when the structure changes and each node needs to be calculated by it's neighbors. You could just change the CSS properties without doing a force directed update, that way you avoid the force checks.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Is there a redraw() method? Or are you referring to just calling the .attr() method on the nodes/links while avoiding the call to start()?

Comment: I just mean going through each node and updating it's CSS, so yes just go through the `.attr()` method for each node/link. No need to use a start the direct force algorithm if the graph is already balanced.

Comment: D3 is perfectly capable of handling all you want. There's no need to use another library.